# Delete all hyperlinks in HTML

Tags: html, css, href

In my iOS app, I'm using some offline HTML's, but with a lot of links. Because the links are really distracting, I would like to remove them all.

```
<a href="https://www.admin.ch/opc/de/classified-compilation/19995395/index.html#ani1"><strong>Präambel</strong></a>
```

I first tried with Find and Replace `<a href="` but then the URL is still shown. Every URL is different so I can't include that in find and replace..

Does anyone have an idea how I might be able to Find and Replace `<a href="x">` where x can be any text? Or any tool to simply remove them all?

Thank you very much. Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: Does the editor you're using support regular expressions? Do you also wish to delete the linked text, or just the link around the text?

Comment: So you want to remove the `<a>` elements from the DOM, leaving only the child elements inside it?

Comment: Yes indeed, I would like to keep the text inside the link but remove the link itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the client doesn't like the blue underlining of links (per your comment to karlo's answer), just reset them using CSS:

```
a {
    color: #000; /* or whatever colour you prefer - you may also use inherit */
    text-decoration: none;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Notice that we use [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to remove any bound click events on the links (thus preventing them from being clicked by the user).

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/cnmd8b1j/)

Comment: This is really useful! Exactly what I needed!

Comment: Or even better, use `color: inherit;` that "rollsback" to the parent color.

Comment: @BramRoelandts No problem at all! Glad I could suggest a useful solution.

Answer (score -1):

It is easy to repalce the url in all your `<a>` tags if you wanna use jQuery.

You just have to put the following codes:

```
    jQuery('body').find('a').attr('href', '#');
```

That will help if you want to remove it using jQuery.

Comment: This would be useful so that the user can't go to the link, but the problem is visually. My clients don't like the blue underlining of the link, so I would like to delete them.

Comment: He actually wants to remove the elements from the DOM. Simply setting the `href` attribute to `#` leaves the element in place. Also, the OP does not mention jQuery.

Comment: Yes indeed @BenM that's what I meant.

Comment: @BramRoelandts see my answer.

Answer (score -1):

jquery can also do this. this will remove all hyperlink as you would like to delete all hyperlink in your html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").remove();
});
```